# The div size did not count in the float right element

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I would like to have some content like this

```
News Event Title                     11.11.2015
-----------------------------------------------
News Event Title 2345 News Event Title 2345 
                                     11.11.2015
-----------------------------------------------
News Event Title News Event Title News Event Ti
tle                                  11.11.2015
```

But it turn out like this

```
News Event Title                     11.11.2015
-----------------------------------------------
News Event Title 2345 News Event Title 2345
----------------------------------------------- 
                                     11.11.2015
News Event Title News Event Title News Event Ti
tle                                  11.11.2015
```

Notice that the second title in the actual result. It is because the date is float: right and does not count into the div size.

How to fix that? Thanks for helping

The code is like

```
<div style="border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;">
<p>News Event Title<span style="float:right;">11.11.2015</span></p>
</div>
```

**Update:**

Please have a look at the demo site, the left bottom corner

**Update**

Overflow:hidden solve the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add the full code that reproduces the issue you are seeing.

Comment: please have a look at update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `overflow: hidden;` on the parent div.

Comment: Thanks a lot . please have a look at update question

Answer (score 0):

```
add clear:both in end of it like this

<div style="border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;">
<p>News Event Title<span style="float:right;">11.11.2015</span></p>
</div> 
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . please have a look at update question

Answer (score 0):

For best practice, you should do like this:

```
<div style="border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;">
<p style=" margin-bottom:0;">News Event Title</p>
<div style="display:block; text-align: right;">11.11.2015</div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/aLLv9odf/1/)**